# CheckBox control in asp.net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I added a checkbox to my form.

When the checkbox is checked, some information (TextBox, Label etc.) should appear right under the checkbox.

How can I do this?

Code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

C#:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't forget `autopostback = true`

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1"></asp:Panel>
```

-

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Text goes here" });
}
```

This allows you to add any control you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just add TextBox, Label etc. controls and make them invisible. 
Then in the `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` function make them visible.
This is done by setting the bool `Visible` property

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox" runat="server" Visible=false />
```

and

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: you should wrap all your controls in a panel. It will be more simple to change the visibility of a single panel control than a lot of other controls. Moreover, the structural html tags will also be shown/hidden along the server controls

Answer (score 1):

Add a new literal control under your checkbox tags,

```
<asp:Literal id="lblMsg" runat="server"/>
```

then in your CheckBox1_CheckedChanged event to this:

```
lblMsg.Text = "Checked";
```

and yes set the `AutoPostBack` property of your checkbox to `true`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this using javascript. Your users won't have to "postback" and the feeling on the application will be better, and you will reduce the server charge.

Using jQuery, you can use something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#chk").onclick(function() {
          $("#content").toggle();
      });
  });
</script>
<input type="Checkbox" id="chk"/>
<div id="content" style="display:none">
       <asp:TextBox runat="Server" id="oneOfYourControls" />
</div>
```

jQuery is not mandatory... you can use standard simple `getElementById()`.

The only drawback, is that you cannot dynamically build the content, but in most case it's a not actually a matter

Answer (score 0):

In Checked Changed Event write your code like this:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label1.Text = "Text";
}
```